# Youtube auto subcribe is possible with api v3?

Tags: youtube

I want to know how can I do auto subcribe an account with youtube api v3. Can I it to register with youtube account. For example, some script do auto post share on your twitter account.

Answer (score 0):

I do not personally use YouTube API, but after looking over the YouTube Data API's documenation pages, it seems that the API supports a method to subscribe users to a channel.

The [API Overview documentation page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/) states:

> A `subscription` resource contains information about a YouTube user subscription. A subscription notifies a user when new videos are added to a channel or when another user takes one of several actions on YouTube, such as uploading a video, rating a video, or commenting on a video.

You may view all the methods supported by the `subscription` resource on [the subscription resource's documentation page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions). The method that you would need is called `insert`. This allows you to automatically subscribe an authenticated user to a specified channel. The `insert` method's description can be found on [its page along with detailed usage examples](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/insert). The page provides examples in Apps Script, Java, PHP, Python, and Ruby; however this method can be used any programming language which supports the YouTube Data API Client Libraries.